# Download to SD card

Tags: downloading

I put a 32gb SD card in my Nokia 2.2 yesterday and I've been wondering how to make my downloads from the Google Play store go straight to my sd card not internal storage. Because when I Try download an app for 1.6gb it goes to my internal storage which doesn't have enough space but my sd card does have enough space and I've been wondering how to change it from downloading to the internal storage to external SD card

Comment: https://android.stackexchange.com/tags/adoptable-storage/info

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if you can install directly to SD from the Play Store but you can move **SOME** apps to your SD after they have been installed.

1. Go to Settings > Apps & notifications > App info.
2. Find the app you want to move in the list and tap it.
3. Select Storage. If the app supports being moved to a card, you’ll see a button here labeled Change. Tap this.
4. Select the SD Card in the Change storage dialog box. This brings up a confirmation screen. Tap Move to begin.